# Can you guess who am I?

Tags: riddle

> I'm just a youngling wandering through time, over 4 decades you can say.

> I always appreciated life itself and its culture. You can say it is the basis of my existence.

> I'll never ever come back home, but that's okay.

> What I've seen, what I remember will be shared among all existence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could be

> [Voyager 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyager_1)

I'm just a youngling wandering through time, over 4 decades you can say.

> Launched in 1977, it is over 40 years old

I always appreciated life itself and its culture. You can say it is the basis of my existence.

> Inside Voyager 1 is the Golden Record containing excerpts of the history of earth and mankind. This will hopefully be seen by any Extra Terrestrial life, so they can gain knowledge as to who we are/were.

I'll never ever come back home, but that's okay.

> Voyager 1 is not projected to come back to earth as it is travelling outside of our solar system.

What I've seen, what I remember will be shared among all existence.

> It sends its data back to us, at least until it can't anymore.